# How to pass data from controller to view by using something like ViewBag in Play Framework

Tags: playframework

In C# there is `ViewBag` which passes data from controller to view e.g `ViewBag.Message = "This is a message"` and we call it `@ViewBag.Message` in View. Is there anything like this in Java Play Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding of your comment that you commented in @jsonmurphy's answer, You can also do like this:

`controllers.Application.search(start: Int)` means, in your controller search function starts like this `public static Result search(int start)`. Since you already have `start` variable, it is possible to pass it to view. What you need to do is to write `start` in your `return` e.g: `return Results.ok(search.render(start));`

In the View
`@(start: Int)`. You can use it like `@start` in anywhere. E.g: `<h1>Start value is @start</h1>`

If you want to pass more than one variable, it is better to use mapping that is explained by @jsonmurphy

Answer (score 1):

No I don't believe so. Simply because Java doesn't have a similar *language level* construct to C#'s dynamic type (specifically [`System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/09/30/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject/)). You can emulate this by using a regular Dictionary/HashMap but of course it would be less elegant:

```
HashMap<String, String> mymap = new ...;
mymap.put("Message","This is a message");
ok(views.html.someview(mymap));
```

and in the view:

```
@(themap: Map[String, String])
....
@themap.get("Message")
```

Comment: I just need to pass one int variable. That variable is also in my url. `GET  /search/*start/    controllers.Application.search(start: Int)
` I  need to take its value and use it in html.